# Assert Dictionary types are the types there supposed to be

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary

We have a Dll that is used in a lot of programs I have been tasked with writing some unit test to assert that it basically isn't changed, testing all the returned objects.

The section I am having the most issues with is the Dictionary types. I would like to assert that e.g.  bob.newfilter is a returned dictionary of type  Dictionary.

the dll code in question returns a filter object

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Crazy.dll
{
    public class Filters
    {
        public Dictionary<int, bool> ColourIsVisible;
        public Dictionary<string, bool> AlphaFilter;
        public Dictionary<string, bool> RedIsVisible;
        public Dictionary<string, bool> BlueFilter;
        public Dictionary<string, bool> BlueIsVisible;
        public Dictionary<string, bool> GreenIsVisible;
        public Filters() // <-- returned object bit interested in testing
        {
            ColourIsVisible = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
            AlphaFilter = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            RedIsVisible = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            BlueFilter = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            BlueIsVisible = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            GreenIsVisible = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
       }
    }
}
```

(please no comment on this code as it is what it is)

I have tried a few variations using Nunit and Microsoft's Test Framework to try to Assert that bob.GreenIsVisible is a returned Dictionary of  type

```
Assert.AreEqual<Dictionary<string,bool>>(bob.GreenIsVisible, new Dictionary<string,bool>());
CollectionAssert.AllItemsAreInstancesOfType(bob.GreenIsVisible, Dictionary<string, bool>);
```

all have returned the same information

Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. 
Expected:
    .

(to me they look the same)

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to compare the types, not the objects since the objects will not be equal

Comment: oh pants comes to mind, All this was caused by me indirectly calling a wrong assert (Assert.IsNotInstanceOf<Dictionary<string,bool>>(bob.GreenIsVisible); ) should have been Assert.IsInstanceOf<Dictionary<string,bool>>(bob.GreenIsVisible,"error message"); thanks Sami caused to take a better look

Comment: Simply *compiling* a test that assigns the property to a `Dictionary<string,bool>` will work. Why write a test?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're testing here. If the property is of type `Dictionary<string,bool>` it is guaranteed to hold `null` or instance of `Dictionary<string,bool>`. So, your test makes no sense for me at-least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the [`Assert<T>(T, T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243427.aspx) which by the documentation:

> Verifies that two specified generic type data are equal by using the equality operator. The assertion fails if they are not equal.

Therefore it won't work here since the objects are naturally not ever equal. You should be using [`Assert.IsInstanceOfType(Object, Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243748.aspx) to check this.

Comment: I actually used Assert.IsInstanceOf<Dictionary<string,bool>>(bob.GreenIsVisible,"Message when they don't match");
This is using the Nunit.Framework

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Assert.IsInstanceOfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243748.aspx) method here since you need to check the type of object and not the actual value or instance equiality.